# new files showing in multiple branch

Tags: git

I have created some files in a branch called "new", and added some file there.
But, those new files are shown in master as well.

```
$ git branch 
  gh-pages
* master
  modify
  new
$ git status 
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    scalable/apps/dbeaver.svg
    scalable/apps/kazam.svg
    scalable/apps/mysql-workbench.svg

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git checkout new 
Switched to branch 'new'
$ git status 
On branch new
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    scalable/apps/dbeaver.svg
    scalable/apps/kazam.svg
    scalable/apps/mysql-workbench.svg

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely normal and the last sentence of the output of `git status` tells you why:

> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

The files are not tracked by Git yet. They do not belong to any branch because they were never committed to the repository.

You must [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) then [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) in order to make those file belong to a commit. A branch is just one pointer to a commit.

Comment: ok, so, the workflow should be, ``(in branch new) add-> commit->checkout to master->merge new``, 
Am i correct?

Comment: Read more about [Git basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics). There is a nice diagram on the "The Three States" section.

Answer (score 2):

It's totally normal since you haven't commit these files. They will follow your checkouts, so you can commit them on the branch you want. That's a natural behavior from git.